# Using select results as variable in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Let's say that I want assign few select statement results in variable, like I would do that in Python. How that query should look like? I tried WITH alias AS () but without success.
What I want to archive is to calculate delta between two specific messages.

I looking for something like this:

```
time1 = ()
time2 = ()

result = time2-time1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly do this with an anonymous code block. But it would probably be far better to write this as a function.

Something like this might be what you're looking for:

```
DO $$
DECLARE time1 TIMESTAMP;
DECLARE time2 TIMESTAMP;
BEGIN
    SELECT '2022-02-15 14:52:51.252859+01'::timestamp INTO time1;
    SELECT '2022-02-15 19:52:51.252859+01'::timestamp INTO time2;
    RAISE NOTICE 'result = %', time2 - time1;
END
$$;
```

Comment: I got this error after I place my selects in BEGIN block.  `SQL Error [22P02]: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type integer: "2022-02-15 14:52:51.252859+01"
  Where: PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 5 at SQL statement`

Comment: Edited my answer - I didn't realise you were using timestamps

Comment: sweet, that works fine for simple task. Thanks!

Comment: Note that `DECLARE` starts a block in PL/pgSQL where multiple variables can be declared. There is no need to start a new block for each variable. Also not relevant for this question, but: assignment using `:=` is faster than a SELECT INTO (`time1 := '...';`)